# How to implement DRY principle in C for looping over matrices

Tags: c, loops, dry

When dealing with two-dimensional arrays, e.g. matrices you need to visit elements quite often. The straight forward way to do this is by two nested loops:

```
for( int i=0; i < n; ++i ) {
  for( int j=0; j < m; ++j ) {
     // do something with data[i][j]
  }
}
```

This code principle then is often copied over and over again throughout the code. How do you solve this to become DRY? I think the only way to solve this is to use a visitor function with function pointers, right?

Edit: To be more constructive, lets assume you have matrix type `typedef double** Matrix;`.

For C++ this might be solved this way: [Loop over matrix elements applying variable function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447546/loop-over-matrix-elements-applying-variable-function)

Comment: You could create a macro that would generate these loops.

Comment: Yes, you could use function or macro in this cases.

Comment: A macro would likely either be messy (non-obvious to the reader) to call or would create phantom hidden `i` and `j` vars (also non-obvious to the reader), If you create the hidden vars, they also could not be nested.

Comment: Oh, yes I totally forgot about macros. I rarely use them, as it is very easy to make mistakes...

Answer (score 3):

First job: consider recasting `data` as a `struct` representing the matrix, or, failing that, a simple `typedef`. I'll assume you do the former.

"`// do something with data[i][j]`" could be a *function* (a `foo` say) that takes `i`, `j`, and a pointer to the matrix `struct` as arguments.

Then you only need one function that does the looping: that function takes the *function* pointer to an appropriate `foo`, and the matrix `struct` pointer.

Your job is then to implement the various `foo`s, according to your requirements.

**Don't** use macros for this: they make debugging difficult, especially if they introduce hard-coded variable names like `i` and `j`.

Comment: Hmm, I think I need something like boost bind to make tailored visitors. So far with nested functions (which are an GCC extension I am half the way there: http://pastebin.com/3rUz9gEH) But I won't use macros for standard-compliant code of nested functions, nor a library dependency such as http://www.haible.de/bruno/packages-ffcall.html, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216037/what-tools-are-there-for-functional-programming-in-c. Maybe its possible to use variadic functions for that?

Comment: The implementation with variadic functions could look like this: http://pastebin.com/N8JtCfve

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bathsheba for giving hints, I finally came up with solutions involving function pointers, which I am not confident with. The main problem is the creation of the specific functions which might need additional parameters.

Note: Thanks to joop, we need therefore an additional function call, which might be omitted with a macro solution.

For example such a visitor resets all matrix elements with a given value. Another visitor might modify the elements with a set of parameters, or not even need a single parameter. So basically I face the question on a flexible definition of the vistor function type.

BTW: In C++ this can be solved either with `std::bind` or with `templates`.

**Nested Functions:**

Nested functions are a GCC extension, and e.g. not available with Clang. Nonetheless here is the code example:

```
typedef double** Matrix;     
typedef void (*MatrixElementVisitor) ( double* element );

void visitMatrixElements( Matrix m, size_t rows, size_t cols, MatrixElementVisitor fn ) {
  for( size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i ) {
    for( size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j ){
      fn( &m[i][j] );
    }
  }
}

void filM( Matrix m, size_t rows, size_t cols, double val ) {
  void fill( double *element ) {
    *element = val;
  }
  visitMatrixElements( m, rows, cols, fill );
}
```

**Variadic functions:**

```
typedef double** Matrix;
typedef void (*MatrixElementVisitor) ( double* element, va_list args );

void visitMatrixElements( Matrix m, size_t rows, size_t cols, MatrixElementVisitor fn, ... ) {
  va_list args,copy;
  va_start( args, fn );
  for( size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i ) {
    for( size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j ){
      va_copy( copy, args );
      fn( &m[i][j], copy );
      va_end( copy );
    }
  }
  va_end( args );
}

void fill( double *element, va_list args ) {
  *element = va_arg( args, double );
}

void filM( Matrix m, size_t rows, size_t cols, double val ) {
  visitMatrixElements( m, rows, cols, fill, val );
}
```

**void pointer:**

```
typedef double** Matrix;
typedef void (*MatrixElementVisitor) ( double* element, void *args );

void visitMatrixElements( Matrix m, size_t rows, size_t cols, MatrixElementVisitor fn, void *args ) {
  if( m ) {
    for( size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i ) {
      if( m[i] ) {
        for( size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j ){
          fn( &m[i][j], args );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void fill( double* element, void *args ) {
  if( !args ) {
    return;
  }
  *element = *((double*)args);
}


void filM( Matrix m, size_t rows, size_t cols, double val ) {
  visitMatrixElements( m, rows, cols, fill, &val );
}
```

Maybe there exist other ways, I think of using static function variables for the initialization of the visitor function, also involving variadic functions.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Do note that callback functions will not be inlined, so an actual function call will be required for each matrix element.